# Decision Boundary Plot for Support Vector Classifier (distance from separating hyperplane)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am working through the book "Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow" by Aurélien Géron. The code below is written in Python 3.

On the GitHub page for the Chap. 5 solutions to the Support Vector Machine problems there is the following code for plotting the SVC decision boundary (https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/05_support_vector_machines.ipynb):

```
def plot_svc_decision_boundary(svm_clf, xmin, xmax):
    w = svm_clf.coef_[0]
    b = svm_clf.intercept_[0]

    # At the decision boundary, w0*x0 + w1*x1 + b = 0
    # => x1 = -w0/w1 * x0 - b/w1
    x0 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200)
    decision_boundary = -w[0]/w[1] * x0 - b/w[1]

    margin = 1/w[1]
    gutter_up = decision_boundary + margin
    gutter_down = decision_boundary - margin

    svs = svm_clf.support_vectors_
    plt.scatter(svs[:, 0], svs[:, 1], s=180, facecolors='#FFAAAA')
    plt.plot(x0, decision_boundary, "k-", linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(x0, gutter_up, "k--", linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(x0, gutter_down, "k--", linewidth=2)
```

My question is why is the margin defined as `1/w[1]`? I believe the margin should be `1/sqrt(w[0]^2+w[1]^2)`. That is, the margin is half of `2/L_2_norm(weight_vector)` which is `1/L_2_norm(weight_vector)`. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305925/why-does-the-svm-margin-is-frac2-mathbfw.

Is this an error in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Given:

> decision boundary: w0*x0 + w1*x1 + b = **0**
>
> gutter_up: w0*x0 + w1*x1 + b = **1**, i.e. w0*x0 + w1*(x1 **- 1/w1**) + b = **0**
>
> gutter_down: w0*x0 + w1*x1 + b = **-1**, i.e. w0*x0 + w1*(x1 **+ 1/w1**) + b = **0**

corresponding to (x0, x1) in decision boundary line, (x0, x1 **+1/w1**) and (x0, x1 **-1/w1**) are points in gutter_up/down line.

[image: Figure 5-2. Sensitivity to feature scales]

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. But then it seems that calling 1/w1 the margin is a misnomer since 1/w1 is not the orthogonal "distance" between the decision boundary and the gutter.  But 1/w1 is merely the amount by which we must shift x1 whilst x0 fixed to shift the point (x0, x1) to one of our gutter lines. Is this correct?

Comment: the absolute distance is NOT usefull very much, since scale `w0, w1, b` by same amount, you can get whatever you want, but the `Separating Hyperplane` stays same

Comment: Why do we set it to zero?